# SetUserInfo for Collect Tracking Code from subscriber level data pulled from appended URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, conversion, einstein-recommendations

I am attempting to define the user info inside the js needed to SetUserInfo for the Collect Tracking Code implementation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

This will allow our users to be identified inside the analytics dashboard.

[image]

I understand I want to define 'subscriberkey' where it indicates "email" in the code snippet. I also understand I need to append to my URL subscriber level data such as 'subscriberkey' Is there a way to do this manually or do you have to use GA parameters to append? Has anyone successfully implemented the Collect Tracking Code with the user's defined? If so how did you do this? What is the best route to take?

Comment: We took the users ID from our backend rather than an email and inserted it into the tracking code. The problem when you do this, is that einstein recommendation blocks of email will need to be manually changed in html view with different ampscript parameters. You can watch some of my threads i opened or answered. Maybe those will help.